# MongoDB: How can I calculate total count without using $group operator

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have following result:

```
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "London",
        "count" : 499
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "Paris",
        "count" : 135
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "Lviv",
        "count" : 95
    }
]
```

And here is query:

```
 {"$group":{
        _id: "$city",
        "count" : {"$sum":1}
    }
 }
```

So, I want some how to calculate all fields not only grouped. I think it would better to show expected result:

```
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "London",
        "count" : 499,
        "total" : 729
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "Paris",
        "count" : 135,
        "total" : 729
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "Lviv",
        "count" : 95,
        "total" : 729
    }
]
```

Expected result has "total" field which calculated as amount of "count" field (499+135+95 = 729).
**EDITED**: I must use only aggregation framework!

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why not just add that on the client rather than making the DB do extra work, and send the same data to the client many times?

Comment: Because client side doesn't have such functionality, I should do this on the server side.

Comment: What client are you using that can't iterate through the results to produce a total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to count the total number before:

```
db.coll.count( ..., function( err, total ) {
```

and then use that result in your aggregation command:

```
{
    "$group": {
        _id: "$city",
        count: { "$sum": 1 },
        total: total
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you only want to use aggregation framework, try this instead of `db.coll.count()`:

```
{
    "$group": {
        _id: 1,
        count: { "$sum": 1 }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. And probably you made mistake in second group, there is should be `"count": {"$first" : "$count"}`.

Comment: I must correct myself. It is not possible with one call. You need two calls.

Comment: it still doesn't work.
This one calculate total of all fields:
`{
    "$group": {
        _id: 1,
        count: { "$sum": 1 }
    }
}`

But how can I pass `"$city"` field to the next group operator?

Comment: You cannot calculate the total sum of all fields and the sum per city in one (1) call. You have to make two mongo calls.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `db.collection.count()` would give you your result actually. This is because you are actually just summing up ALL documents in the collection there.

Comment: I need count of grouped fields and total of all fields. Please take a look at my expected result. And one more thing, I should use aggregation framework